# Hide and Unhide masterView from button press of detailView

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I know this question has asked by many users,But i did not found any answer related to my issue.

I'm using `UISplitViewController` ,my application starts with login page, so i have hidden `masterView` on start, after some time on `DetailViewController` i shown the master `viewController` using Delegate method.

```
    - (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0)
{
    return hideMaster;
}
```

i have initialised `hideMaster` to `NO` ,and my ViewDidLoad() of `DetailViewController` is below

```
ViewDidLoad(){

[self.splitViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
    self.splitViewController.delegate =Nil;
    self.splitViewController.delegate = self;

    [self.splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication    sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:0];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

it worked fine my master is now unhide.But on the same detailViewController i have a Back Button on which i'm poping the current ViewController to last viewController and again i want to hide masterViewController  my code for back button is below.

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {




hideMaster = NO;

self.splitViewController.delegate =Nil;
self.splitViewController.delegate = self;

[self.splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication    sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:0];


   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

**Its poping the `CurrentViewController` to last `ViewController` but its not Hiding the `masterViewController`**

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JohnD,I went through your code.you are hiding the master view controller while poping the last View controller,but the viewController to which you are navigating is still showing the master View controller.therefore your masterView is still there.

follow the steps given below.

1.make `delegate` of `UInavigationController` to that ViewController which is your last singleView controller.

2.In last single ViewController(which is delegate of UINavigationController) implement following delegate method.

```
  - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[self.splitViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
    self.splitViewController.delegate =Nil;
    self.splitViewController.delegate = self;

    [self.splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication    sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:0];
}
```

3.Now implement delegate method of UISplitViewController in side lastViewController which is given below.

```
    - (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0)
{
    return hideMaster;<<===============I'm assuming hide master as a variable of shared object(Singleton).
}
```

4.Now change your - (IBAction)back:(id)sender method with following one.

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {




hideMaster = Yes;




   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

I hope this will work,if you stuck some where please let me know.

Comment: wali,what do you mean by last single ViewController and "I'm assuming hide master as a variable of shared object(Singleton)" ?

Comment: LastSingleViewController is a ViewController after which you are showing masterViewController in your app,and i'm assuming that you are using hidMaster variable as a member variable of a shared object means a singleton object,Because if you change the value of hideMaster to NO while poping the viewController it should be reflect on previous viewController too

Answer (score 1):

you are using UISplitViewController inside your app,since you have many views  but whole app is not using UISplitViewController only one view using it.

Its better to use another approach.